# Select Multiple Checkbox with datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables, datatables-1.10

I tried to get the value of the check box for each row I have two textbox to store it and separate each value by comma. The problem is when I paginate or use search in datatable the value of two textbox is resetting with the value that I checked in another page or search. It should be continuously storing the value.

```js
$(".trio").change(function() {
  setValue();
  setValue2();
});

$(".Duo").change(function() {
  setValue();
  setValue2();
});

function setValue() {
  var items = $(".trio");
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = $(items[i]);
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      result.push(item.val());
    }
  }
  var text = result.join(",");
  $(".DISTRIBUTION").val(text);
}

function setValue2() {
  var items = $(".Duo");
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = $(items[i]);
    if (item.is(":checked")) {
      result.push(item.val());
    }
  }
  var text = result.join(",");
  $(".DuoC").val(text);
}

$('.trio').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.Duo').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$('.Duo').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('.trio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='1' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='1' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='2' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='2' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='3' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='3' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='4' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='4' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='5' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='5' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='6' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='6' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='7' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='7' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='8' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='8' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='9' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='9' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='10' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='10' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='11' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='11' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='12' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='12.' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='13' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='13.' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>



      </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<br/>TRIO:
<input type="text" class="DISTRIBUTION" />Duo
<input type="text" class="DuoC" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a problem of variable:

```js
var duo = [];
var trio = [];


$('.trio').on('click', function() {
  var s = $(this).siblings('.Duo').not(this).prop('checked');
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    trio.push($(this).val());
  } else {
    trio.splice(trio.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }
  if (s) {
    $(this).siblings('.Duo').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    duo.splice(duo.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }

  var text = trio.join(",");
  $(".DISTRIBUTION").val(text);
  text = duo.join(",");
  $(".DuoC").val(text);
});

$('.Duo').on('click', function() {
  var s = $(this).siblings('.trio').not(this).prop('checked');
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    duo.push($(this).val());
  } else {
   duo.splice(duo.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }  
  if (s) {
    $(this).siblings('.trio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    trio.splice(trio.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }

  var text = trio.join(",");
  $(".DISTRIBUTION").val(text);
  text = duo.join(",");
  $(".DuoC").val(text);
});

$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='1' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='1' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='2' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='2' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='3' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='3' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='4' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='4' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='5' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='5' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='6' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='6' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='7' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='7' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='8' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='8' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='9' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='9' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='10' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='10' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='11' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='11' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='12' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='12' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='13' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='13' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>



      </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<br/>TRIO:
<input type="text" class="DISTRIBUTION" />Duo
<input type="text" class="DuoC" />
```

if you keep only 2 checkboxes, you could simplify and generalize your code:

```js
var duo = [];
var trio = [];

$('.Duo, .trio').on('click', function() {
  var claz = "." + $(this).attr("class").trim();
  var s = $(this).siblings();
  var a0 = claz == ".trio" ? trio : duo;
  var b0 = claz == ".trio" ? duo : trio;
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    a0.push($(this).val());
  } else {
    a0.splice(a0.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }
  if (s.prop('checked')) {
    s.prop('checked', false);
    b0.splice(b0.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
  }

  var text = trio.join(",");
  $(".DISTRIBUTION").val(text);
  text = duo.join(",");
  $(".DuoC").val(text);
});

$(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='1' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='1' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='2' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='2' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='3' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='3' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='4' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='4' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='5' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='5' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='6' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='6' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='7' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='7' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='8' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='8' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='9' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='9' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='10' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='10' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='11' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='11' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='12' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='12' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Trio <input class="trio" value='13' name="trio[]" type="checkbox"> Duo <input class="Duo" value='13' Name="Duo[]" type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>



      </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<br/>TRIO:
<input type="text" class="DISTRIBUTION" />Duo
<input type="text" class="DuoC" />
```

Comment: the problem here is you did not remove the duplicate. example you have 12 in one textbox when i click the another checkbox it should be transfer to another

Comment: @CarlodManlulu its fixed!